# Transform Pandas Datetime to Eastern Time from Unix Epoch Time on multiple columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have seen tons of date questions asked on stack overflow, but not one address specifically what I need to do here.

```
df['UNIXTIME']=pd.to_datetime(pd['UNIXTIME'], unit='ms')\
                 .dt.tz_localize('UTC' )\
                 .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

I need to apply it to about 5 columns at once.  What is the best way to use the .apply method to use the above code on multiple columns?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df.loc[:, cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('America/New_York'))
```